# $f:R \to S$, a surjective ring homomorphism $\implies$ $R/\ker f \cong S$. Is this part of my proof correct?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $f:R \to S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. I want to show $R/\ker f \cong S$.

$I:=\ker f$.

Define $\psi: R/I \to S$ by $\psi(a+I)=f(a)$.

$\psi$ is one to one and well defined:
$\psi(a+I)=\psi(b+I) \iff f(a)=f(b) \iff f(a)-f(b)=0 \iff f(a-b)=0\iff a-b \in \ker f \iff a-b \in I \iff a+I=b+I$

with the last equivalence following form that fact that $I$ is a normal subgroup of $R$.

Question: Is my proof that the prospective isomorphism $\psi$ is one to one and well defined correct? I know this is a terrible reason to doubt oneself, but it seems too simple and I am paranoid that I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Need to show surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. If you want to be more rigorous, try justifying each double implication (i.e. $f(a)-f(b)=0\iff f(a-b)=0$ **since $f$ is a homomorphism**, etc.).

What's next? You have to show that $\psi$ is surjective (this one is easy, I promise) and that it's a homomorphism. How would you do that?